# Asynchronously authenticate before request

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, axios

So I have an API and I am trying to authenticate by hitting an endpoint with credentials (this part I've gotten working) and then save the received token and use it in all subsequent requests.

My problem is that the `authenticate()` method is asynchronous, but all other request methods like `get()` need the token from the `authenticate()` method. So I can't just export my `get()` method because the export is synchronous (as I've read) and it will be exported before authentication happens. I could authenticate for every request but that seems wasteful and inefficient.

I am not sure what to do here, I'm using axios, what's the proper way of doing this?

Edit

I'll be a bit more specific here. I have created an axios instance:

```
var instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://${config.server}:${config.port}`,
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
})
```

I want to get the authentication token, and include it in the instance header:

```
async function authenticate(instance) {
  const result = await instance.post(
    '/session',
    {
      'username': config.username,
      'password': config.password
    }
  )
  instance['X-Token'] = result.data.token
}
```

Now I want to export that instance to be used in other files

Comment: you can await it if you have ES6.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: Can you show me an example? Pseudocode is fine

Comment: Sure.  `const token = await authenticate()
const res = get(endpoint, token);
`

Comment: @ruby_newbie `await` was introduced in ECMAScript 2017, not in ECMAScript 2015 (aka ES6)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `async/await`.  This is semi-pseudocode:

```
async function doStuff() {
  const result = await axios.authenticate();
  const token = // extract token from whatever format of result is
  const data = await axios.get(/* supply token to get */); 
}
```

Alternatively, you can just use `then`:

```
function doStuff(token) {
  const token = // extract token from whatever format of result is
  const data = await axios.get(/* supply token to get */); 
}

axios.authenticate().then(result => {
  const token = // extract token from whatever format of result is
  doStuff(token);
}
```

Comment: Ok, but this model is on a per request basis. I want to save the token, include it in the axios instance header, and then be able to make requests using that instance and not having to manually include the header every time

Comment: One way to do this is to to use authenticate().then() chain on first request (or if token is not present), and skip it if token is present for subsequent requests.

Comment: So for every API call I would need to have a built in conditional to check if the token is set before I make the request? Is there not a way to set the token once, assign it to an axios instance, and then import that instance into whatever files require it to make API calls?

Comment: You can but you need to make sure that happens before your first call to `get()`.

Comment: Haha, yes! That is exactly what I want to do, I just don't know how!

Answer (score 2):

[With Axios you have the ability to set default values for all requests.](https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults)

So for just a single axios instance you can do...

```
async function authenticate(instance) {
  const result = await instance.post(
    '/session',
    {
      'username': config.username,
      'password': config.password
    }
  )
  instance.defaults.headers.common['X-Token'] = result.data.token;
}
```

Alternatively, (which it sounds like you want to do) you can add it for the default Axios export.  Then all requests will automatically have the header.

```
async function authenticate(endpoint, username, password) {
  const res = await axios.post(`${endpoint}/session`, { username, password });
  axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Token'] = result.data.token; 
}
```

Then you don't have to worry about passing around an instance between all parts of your app and can just use `import * as axios from 'axios'` and have the header set.

---

[Axios also provides and extremely helpful function called interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) which you can use to inspect a request prior to making it.  You can use to check to make sure that the request has the auth header and if it doesn't you can perform that logic.  I came up with this and it seems to work well!

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  // request intercepted, check (1) the header is missing and (2) that the intercepted request isn't authorizing
  if (!config.headers.common['X-Token'] && config.authorizing !== true) {
    const { endpoint, username, password } = appConfig;

    // make a request to get your token AND pass our custom config
    const result = await axios.post(`${endpoint}/session`, { username, password }, { authorizing: true });

    // update axios to include the header for future requests
    axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Token'] = result.data.token;
  }
  return config;
});
```

Two things that you'll want to note -- not only do I check for the existence of your X-token header I also check for a new authorization value in the config.  You want to check for that config value, because we are going to use it as a flag to let the interceptor know if it should skip a request.  If you don't do this, the authorization request will trigger another authorization request and infinite loop.

Comment: Apologies for the somewhat late reply, and thank you for your response. I see how this is valuable, but I still don't see how I can run this authentication step synchronously so that I have the token set in the header before I make any other api calls. Maybe I am just being an idiot, but it would really help me out if you had some kind of example perhaps?

Comment: Okay I get what you want to do, I updated my answer to provide that logic!